# How to retrieve German Umlauts: u'\\nAm Boden zerst\\xf6rte Gladiator

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I am pretty sure that this is a very basic question but after hours of searching and many attempts to fix this myself I still havent made progress.

Umlauts in my json file are saved like this. I found lots of ways to go from ö -> \xf6 but how can I go the other way round and end up with a utf-8 encoded file?

Comment: How are you saving your json and what are you using to read it.

Comment: The file is the result of a Scrapy crawl, I use infile = json.load(open(forum_filepath, 'r')) to read it (Mac, Sublime editor). Scrapy ran on Win7 -- possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment I'd assume you're using python. When using json.load, parse it the utf-8 encoding parameter.

Look at the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Thank you for your repy - I ultimately scraped again and didn't encounter any issues then, not sure what the cause was...